# Errors using pyinstall to create exe file, last error: 'ImportError: Unable to load module attribute'

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I have a simple .ipynb that reads a value from one excel file, and prints it to a cell in another excel file. I use 'jupyter nbconvert --to script MyFile.ipynb to generate .py file. This works, no error. .py file is created.

In terminal:

```
C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Scripts>jupyter nbconvert --to script MyFile.ipynb
```

Output:

```
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook MyFile.ipynb to script
[NbConvertApp] Writing 1034 bytes to MyFile.py
```

I then go:

```
C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Scripts>pyinstaller --onefile MyFile.py
```

I then get:

```
raise ImportError('Unable to load module attribute') from e
ImportError: Unable to load module attribute
```

This is my stop point now, and I can figure it out. I find information about adding paths etc., but I don't really understand what to do?

The history is like this, I first got 'maximum recursion depth exceeded error'. I tried to solve this by altering spec file with:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

I then ran -C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Scripts>pyinstaller --onefile MyFile.py' again, with no luck. Spec file was over-written.

I then ran 'pyinstaller MyFile.spec' this did not work.

I then found somewhere that the version of openpyxl could be the issue, and I uninstalled current version, and installed openpyxl 2.3.5. I then deleted my .py file and started over to be on the safe side. After doing this I got the above 'ImportError: Unable to load module attribute' error.

It seems like I keep moving towards getting an exe file in the end here, but it sure isn't as easy as some forums would like it to be.

What am I doing wrong? How can I improve my overall code/ setup to reach my goal of a functional exe file? I am using windows, and the users of the exe file will be windows based.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you put the full traceback here, as it's hard to guess exactly which module. And put your .spec file as well. Some form of reproducible code from MyFile.py will also help in debugging the issue

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and for me the cause of my version of matplotlib. There appears to be a current known bug with matplotlib version 3.3.x. Downgrading to 3.1.2 fixed my issue. Also if you are using Anaconda Navigator I would recommend creating a dedicated Python environment solely for packaging your script.